# Open Failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) when uploading image using Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, kotlin, file-upload, retrofit

i've been trying to send image that has been selected in gallery to the server using Retrofit2, but it always gave me error like `content:/com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A28: open failed:ENOENT (No such file or directory)`. I assume it's because the path is incorrect, because when i check to gallery the path looks like this `/storage/emulated/0/Download/images.png`. Is there anyways i can get the correct path ? or can i get the image using the path i get using `URI` ? Thanks.

**Choose Image Code :**

```
fun submitFirstKm(view: View) {
    Log.d("Path Image", "Path Image : $filepath")
    CustomWarningDialog(this, batteryPercentage.toString(), "12312312.123123", edt_first_km.text.toString(), filepath.toString())
        .showDialog(Constants.WARNING_DIALOG, "first_km").show()
}

fun startFileChooser(view: View) {
    val i = Intent()
    i.type = "image/*"
    i.action = Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(i, "Choose Picture"), REQUEST_CODE)
}

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        filepath = data.data!!
        val bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(contentResolver, filepath)
        img_first_km.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
    }
}
```

**Upload Code :**

```
private fun submit(){
    try {
        val file: File = File(uri)
        val requestFile: RequestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/*".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        val filePhoto : MultipartBody.Part = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file",file.name,requestFile)
        val firstKm: RequestBody = km.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
        val coordinates: RequestBody = coordinate.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)
        val batteryPercentage: RequestBody = batteryPercentage.toRequestBody(MultipartBody.FORM)

        ApiConfig().getService()
            .firstKm(firstKm, coordinates, batteryPercentage, filePhoto)
            .enqueue(object : Callback<FirstKmResponse> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<FirstKmResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Gagal : ${t.message}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }

                override fun onResponse(
                    call: Call<FirstKmResponse>,
                    response: Response<FirstKmResponse>
                ) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Berhasil", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "Gagal : ${response.code()}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            })
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("FirstKmException", "Exception $e")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java

// use the FileUtils to get the actual file by uri
File file = FileUtils.getFile(this, fileUri);

//Tutorial
https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-upload-files-to-server